# How can I specify multiple startup tasks in Conemu?

Tags: command-line, conemu

How can I specify multiple startup tasks in Conemu? I want to have each task in a separate tab opened on startup.
Something like:

```
ConEmu64.exe /cmdlist {Powershell}|{FAR}|{VSConsole}
```

Unfortunately, this command does not support "console scripts" ("Console script are not supported here").

I know, I can create another task, combining the commands of my desired tasks (full commands, because task command does not support console scripts). Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of `/cmdlist` was giving to user ability of starting several commands without creating exact named task. Say, this is an extra "unnamed" task, nothing more. Actually, it was created for simplifying debugging process without need of task creation ;)

The task, by-turn, is a "script" where user can show what command (Tab or Pane) must become active after startup. If you run several tasks at once - what command of what task must become active? Incomprehensible... Also, there may be a risk of infinite recursive task calling.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So I guess I will stick with the "meta-task" combining the desired commands.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old one, but I was looking for an answer.  There is a ConEmu FAQ that answers this question:

> Q. Is it possible to set up ConEmu to open multiple tabs on startup (e.g., Far, CMD, PowerShell)?
>   [ConEmu FAQ Q6-1](http://conemu.github.io/en/FAQ-6.html#q-6-1)

Basically the answer is to create a text file with commands and pass to ComEmu on startup:

```
conemu.exe /cmd @startfile.txt
```

Comment: I did see that too, I didn't understand the significance of the '@' in the file name and not having path to it -
 but it seemed to work anyway without the @ - unfortunately not for git shell. So my work around was to use the option 'Save and re-open session' which works pretty well considering all I wanted was a git (bash) shell and a cmd shell side by side. Hope this helps someone looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

mine is more twisted... because i'm using cmder, not sure howt 
1) windows shortcut <== 2) ConEmu task <== 3) bat <== 4) commnads


------------------------------ goes:------------------------------------
1) in windows shortcut properties: target:

```
C:\tools\cmder.v1.3.6\Cmder.exe /task uniqlo-mvns
```

2) in cmder () settings -> startup -> tasks: 
task name: `uniqlo-mvns` 
task command: `cmd /k "C:\uniqlo.bat" new_console:t:"hahaha"`

3) in `uniqlo.bat`:

```
@start cmd /k mvn -f C:\1\pom.xml
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
@start cmd /k mvn -f C:\2\pom.xml
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
@start cmd /k mvn -f C:\3\pom.xml
```